# Firebase Security - How to allow to push to a node AND update subtree on that node?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I feel this is a pretty common question, but as I've been learning Firebase security, I still can't seem to hack this small issue where I have a tree node that I want to be able to push new data to, while simultaneously be able to update existing nodes. According to the Firebase documentation, if you put these rules in your top-level tree, you should be able to create/delete, but not update:

```
".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
```

So when I use the Firebase database simulator with authentication and everything, I go to simulate a "write" on a path `/social/bands`, however I get a `Simulated write denied`. I should note that in this path, data does exist.

My full rules for this example look like:

```
"social": {
   "bands": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists() && auth != null",
     "$bandId": {
        ".write": "auth != null && data.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() === true"
     }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to be able to create/delete nodes on my `/social/bands` tree, while simultaneously being able to nodes that exist like `/social/bands/$bandId`, whether or not data exists in the path? I feel this is a common thing that happens.

I should note that I'm trying to implement these rules this inside the context of an Ionic 3 app, utilizing AngularFire, if that should make any difference at all (which I don't believe that it would, as the simulator is giving me the permission errors).

Update: Here is a screenshot of the simulator fail:

[image]

Here is the data I'm trying to write in the simulator

```
{
  "admins" : {
    "ruNdZP2Gx6bqsovL8gMlLJP9g0a2" : true
  },
  "creator_id" : "ruNdZP2Gx6bqsovL8gMlLJP9g0a2",
  "followers" : 2,
  "genres" : [ "Classical" ],
  "looking_for_musicians" : true,
  "members" : {
    "ruNdZP2Gx6bqsovL8gMlLJP9g0a2" : true
  },
  "name" : "Radiant and the beach",
  "social_profiles" : {
    "soundcloud" : ""
  }
}
```

The path I'm writing to is `/social/bands`.

Here is the authentication state in the simulator:

[image]

Here is the existing data in the tree with one of the nodes expanded:

[image]

And the error message is just the Simulator write denied issue that I mentioned previously.

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the failing write in the simulator that shows the path you're writing to, the data you write, the authentication state, the existing JSON data, and the error message?

Comment: Hey Frank, I've gone ahead and everything that you asked for to the best of my knowledge. Any idea what could be causing the problem here?

Comment: Almost. :-) Can you add a screenshot of the path you're writing to and the value you're writing? This is one of the few cases where I prefer a screenshot of the actual data. I often find it easiest to capture all of these (rules, path, data, auth state) in a single (large) screenshot. Normally these are not ideal for SO, but it's the best I've found for this situation.

Comment: The screenshot of the path I'm writing to and the value I'm trying to write are all there. In terms of getting it in an entire screenshot, it wouldn't be able to showcase everything I'm trying to do haha. But everything you need should be there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to write to `/social/bands`. On that level you have a rule `!data.exists()`. There is already data under `/social/bands`, such as the band named `My Awesome Band`. Since data already exists, the `!data.exists()` evaluates to false and the write is rejected.

If you want users to be able to add new bands, you should move that rule down to the level of a specific band in your JSON:

```
"social": {
   "bands": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     "$bandId": {
        ".write": "auth != null && (
          !data.exists() || !newData.exists() ||
          data.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() === true
        )"
     }
   }
}
```

In words: any authenticated user can add or delete a band, only admins can modify a band.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for the response! This does make sense, but what's weird is that when I apply the rules that you have suggested, when I try to write to `/social/bands`, I still get a simulator write permission denied. However, when I try to write to a band that already exists in the tree, such as `/social/bands/-KoDm_9yU6JrhOKUPOEW`. Do I have to do something where I'm always writing to some node, even if it doesn't exist yet? I would have thought writing `/social/bands` would be allowed since I need the unique ID that gets generated :( Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh wow. Okay so I learned something incredible about Firebase security just now. I was wrong! I actually tried entering data via my app and it worked! So you were right, but my simulator was just acting funky :)

Comment: So yes, I can't thankyou enough, this has been bothering me for weeks now. Hopefully this helps other people as well <3

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out Stevie! If the simulator in the console was giving wrong results, I'd appreciate a full screenshot of the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44922710/firebase-phone-number-authentication-error